# I need to update ssl binding without changing the IP

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have an azure webapp configured with an IP SSL binding. How do I update the certificate on my IP SSL binding without changing the IP?

Comment: If the reply is helpful, you can accept it or if you need further help, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

When you bind a certificate with IP-based SSL, App Service creates a new, dedicated IP address for your web app. You can find the **virtual IP address** from app service page---properties. If you have mapped an A record to your web app, update your domain registry with this new, dedicated IP address.

> To avoid a change in your app's IP address, follow these steps in
>   order:
>
> 1. Upload the new certificate.
> 2. Bind the new certificate to the custom domain you want without deleting the old one. This action replaces the binding instead of
>      removing the old one.
> 3. Delete the old certificate.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl#renew-certificates